# Cannot deploy Enterprise Application to glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish-3, ear, netbeans-6.9

I've been working on a web application created on Netbeans 6.9.1, and everything works fine and I'm able to deploy it without problems. Today I've created an Enterprise Application and replaced the content of 'web' and 'src' folders on the Enterprise Application web module with the folders from the original web application.
Everything seems ok, it compiles without problems and generates the ear file when I run 'clean and build'. But when I try to deploy the Enterprise Application, I keep getting the following error: org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: project/dao/MerchantDao

I've looked the structure of the generated ear and it has the expected META-INF and the war file. The war file inside the ear is also ok, I've tried to deploy it separately and it worked fine.

I'm not sure what else I can try, I'm afraid this might be a glassfish bug and I'm just wasting my time.

Can someone help me with this?

Kind regards,

Carlos Jorge Ferreira

Comment: I performed some more tests and realized that if I remove all EJB annotations the application deploys correctly. Am I missing some kind of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are providing enough informations to get an answer about your current problem (e.g. the EAR structure).

Anyway, if you don't have strong modularity needs, my suggestion would be to use [the WAR packaging](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/is_java_ee_6_war) (with Java EE 6, using an EAR is not mandatory and you can package EJBs under `WEB-INF/classes` or under `WEB-INF/lib` if you bundle them as EJB-JAR).

Oh, by the way, I'm deploying a Java EE 6 EAR on GlassFish and it just works.

Comment: Hi Pascal, Thanks for your reply. I've tried other ear files, with ejbs, and I successfully deployed them to glassfish. I'm just having problems with one project. If I put all EJBs in a EJB Module, everything works fine, but as soon as I annotate a class from the WEB module with the @Stateless annotation, I start getting the error.

Comment: @Carlos I'm not sure I'm following everything. Are you using a WAR only or an EAR? In the former case, double check the version of the deployment descriptor of the webapp. In the later case, why are you adding EJB annotations in the web module?

Comment: @Pascal, I'm using an EAR. I don't think it's a question of why am I using an EJB annotation in the WEB module, the real question is: why can't I? I've cheched an example from the netbeans website (The NewsAppEE6 application) and they use EJB annotations on the web module (@Singleton and @LocalBean). If I use the same annotations in one of my classes I can no longer deploy the application. I don't have to use an EAR, I can easily use a WAR, but i just wanted to understand what is causing this error. (BTW, the deployment descriptor is using version 3.0)

Comment: @Carlos It definitely is! The examples on the NetBeans website are very likely using a WAR packaging. However **when** using an EAR packaging, I don't think you can package EJBs in your WAR. Why? Because that's not how things are specified. So while you can waste your time trying to understand why a container doesn't implement something that is not part of the spec, my suggestion would be to follow the rules. Either package your EJBs in a WAR and use a WAR packaging or put them in EJB-JARs if you use an EAR packaging.

Comment: @Pascal The example I'm talking about is using an EAR packaging (In fact, I looked for examples that were using Enterprise Application Projects instead of Web Application). I had no trouble deploying it, and it has EJB annotations in the Web module. I'm just wondering why that project works normally and mine doesn't, but, like you've mentioned, I'm just wasting my time. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Carlos Try to provide some links when you're referring to something, it is usually helpful.

Comment: @Pascal Sorry, here is the link I was talking about: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-entapp-ejb.html